# Swift: for loop, search dictionary, set variables from keys

Tags: swift, string, dictionary

**Error is: Cannot convert value of type (String: Int)? to specified type 'String'.**

Obviously my dictionary 'roster' is 'String: Int' and the local variables ('lastPlayer' and 'firstPlayer') inside function 'printRoster' is String.  But I've tried every variation with no luck.  It worked fine before I made roster a dictionary, and it was just a String.

What it should do: function concatenates a string so that it has correct punctuation.  First string is "The roster includes", then we add on each player located in the Key of the dictionary 'roster'.  But the first key in the roster gets no comma and the last key gets an ', and'.

*Also, can I add the dictionary 'roster' to the protocol, didn't see the syntax in any of the Apple manuals*

```
    import UIKit

protocol basketballTeams {
    var teamName: String? { get }
    var numberOfPlayers: Int? { get }
    var locatedIn: String? { get }

    func printTeamLocation()
}

class BasketballTeam {
    var teamName: String?
    var numberOfPlayers: Int?
    var locatedIn: String?
    var roster = [String: Int]()

    init(teamName: String) {
        self.teamName = teamName
    }

    func printTeamLocation() -> String {
        return "The \(teamName) are located in \(locatedIn)"
    }
    func printRoster() -> String {
        var rosterPrint = "The roster includes"
        for player in roster.keys {

            rosterPrint += player

            var firstPlayer: String = roster.first
            var lastPlayer = roster.last

            if (player == firstPlayer) {
                rosterPrint += " \(player)"
            }
            else if (player == lastPlayer) {
                rosterPrint += ", and \(player)."
            }
            else {
            rosterPrint += ", \(player)"
            }
        }
        return rosterPrint
    }
}

enum NumberedPosition: Int {
    case PointGuard = 1
    case ShootingGuard, SmallForward, PowerForward, Center
    func labelOfPosition() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .PointGuard:
            return "Point Guard"
        case .ShootingGuard:
            return "Shooting Guard"
        case .SmallForward:
            return "Small Forward"
        case .PowerForward:
            return "Power Forward"
        case .Center:
            return "Center"
        default:
            "Position doesn't exit"
        }
    }
}

let goldenStateWarriors = BasketballTeam(teamName: "Golden State Warriors")
goldenStateWarriors.numberOfPlayers = 12
goldenStateWarriors.locatedIn = "Oakland, California"
goldenStateWarriors.roster = ["Stephen Curry" : 1, "Andrew Bogut" : 5, "Klay Thompson" : 2]
goldenStateWarriors.roster["Harrison Barnes"] = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to add the "and" to the last row you can use this function:

```
func printRoster() -> String {
  var rosterPrint = "The roster includes"
  let arr = Array(roster.keys)
  let firstPlayer: String = arr.first!
  let lastPlayer: String = arr.last!
  for (player, _ ) in roster {
    switch player {
    case firstPlayer:
      rosterPrint += " \(player)"
    case lastPlayer:
      rosterPrint += ", and \(player)."
    default:
      rosterPrint += ", \(player)"
    }
   }
   return rosterPrint
}
```

and call it like so:

```
print(goldenStateWarriors.printRoster())
```

Comment: Ok, so essentially swift won't let me do it to a dictionary and I have to copy the keys to a duplicate array, then I can do it.  If this is the case, any chance they could fix this in 3.0?

Comment: Yeah, `roster.keys` returns a `LazyMapCollection` which can't be indexed with an `Int` and has no `last` method, so copying to an array allows you to use the `last` method to set `lastPlayer`. **Edit** I don't think it will be fixed, simply because it isn't broken. A LazyMapCollection allows better access for large dictionaries. @JamesGoldstein

Comment: Would '.count - 1' work without duplicating to an array?

Comment: Unfortunately, `LazyMapCollection`s are not indexable by `Int` values they use their own index type. see here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/lazymapcollection @JamesGoldstein

Comment: Great!  Works well

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
let roster = ["Stephen Curry":1, "Andrew Bogu": 2, "Klay Thompson":3]

let players = roster.keys.joined(separator: ", ")
let all = "Roster contains: \(players)."
```

Comment: So better than my solution, congrats! However please note that in Swift 2.2 the correct syntax is still `joinWithSeparator`

Comment: While this would work, it seems less dynamic than what I'm looking for.  I'd like completely correct grammar and the for loop to work, so that I could build out even more advanced functionality.  Because the next thing I was going to work on was something tying the value to the enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

Given this dictionary

```
let roster = ["Stephen Curry":1, "Andrew Bogu": 2, "Klay Thompson":3]
```

you can

```
let elms = roster
    .keys
    .reduce("") { $0.1 + ", " + $0.0 }
    .characters
    .dropLast()
    .dropLast()

let res = "The roster includes " + String(elms)
```

**Result**

```
"The roster includes Andrew Bogu, Stephen Curry, Klay Thompson"
```

### Update #1: Using the FOR LOOP

Since you want to use the for loop here's the code

```
let roster = ["Stephen Curry":1, "Andrew Bogu": 2, "Klay Thompson":3]
var result = "The roster includes "
for (index, elm) in roster.keys.enumerate() {
    result += elm
    if index < roster.keys.count - 1 {
        result += ", "
    }
}

print(result) // The roster includes Klay Thompson, Stephen Curry, Andrew Bogu
```

### Update #2: Using the FOR LOOP with first and last

```
let roster = ["Stephen Curry":1, "Andrew Bogu": 2, "Klay Thompson":3]

func printRoster() -> String {

    var rosterPrint = "The roster includes"
    let players = Array(roster.keys)


    guard let
        first = players.first,
        last = players.last
        else { return "" } // this is ugly, it should return nil instead...

    for player in players {
        switch player {
        case first: rosterPrint += " \(player)"
        case last: rosterPrint += ", and \(player)."
        default: rosterPrint += ", \(player)"
        }
    }
    return rosterPrint
}

printRoster() // "The roster includes Klay Thompson, Stephen Curry, and Andrew Bogu."
```

Comment: Also simpler than what I was looking for.  I'm looking to keep the for loop. Correct grammar as well.

Comment: @JamesGoldstein: I added the FOR LOOP implementation

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's probably better to use the newer Swift functions .first and .last like above.

Comment: Actually, maybe not.  Looks like I can duplicate keys to an array and use my code with '.last' or '.first', or I can save the duplication step and use '.count - 1'.

Comment: @JamesGoldstein: Just updated again my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well, at least until they allow .first and .last with dictionaries (if that's even possible).

```
    class BasketballTeam {
    var teamName: String?
    var numberOfPlayers: Int?
    var locatedIn: String?
    var roster = [String: Int]()

    init(teamName: String) {
        self.teamName = teamName
    }

    func printTeamLocation() -> String {
        return "The \(teamName) are located in \(locatedIn)"
    }
    func printRoster() -> String {
        var rosterPrint = "The roster includes"
        let rosterArray = Array(roster.keys)

        for player in rosterArray {

            let firstPlayer = rosterArray.first
            let lastPlayer = rosterArray.last

            switch player {
            case firstPlayer!:
                rosterPrint += " \(player)"
            case lastPlayer!:
                rosterPrint += ", and \(player)."
            default:
                rosterPrint += ", \(player)"
            }
        }
        return rosterPrint
    }
}
```

**Full code, you can paste into a playground if you're trying to learn swift and familiar with basketball**

```
import UIKit

protocol basketballTeams {
    var teamName: String { get }
    var numberOfPlayers: Int { get }
    var locatedIn: String { get }
    var roster: [String: Int] { get }

    func printTeamLocation()
}

class BasketballTeam {
    var teamName: String?
    var numberOfPlayers: Int?
    var locatedIn: String?
    var roster = [String: Int]()

    init(teamName: String) {
        self.teamName = teamName
    }

    func printTeamLocation() -> String {
        return "The \(teamName) are located in \(locatedIn)"
    }
    func printRoster() -> String {
        var rosterPrint = "The roster includes"
        let rosterArray = Array(roster.keys)

        for player in rosterArray {

            let firstPlayer = rosterArray.first
            let lastPlayer = rosterArray.last

            switch player {
            case firstPlayer!:
                rosterPrint += " \(player)"
            case lastPlayer!:
                rosterPrint += ", and \(player)."
            default:
                rosterPrint += ", \(player)"
            }
        }
        return rosterPrint
    }
}

enum NumberedPosition: Int {
    case PointGuard = 1
    case ShootingGuard, SmallForward, PowerForward, Center
    func labelOfPosition() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .PointGuard:
            return "Point Guard"
        case .ShootingGuard:
            return "Shooting Guard"
        case .SmallForward:
            return "Small Forward"
        case .PowerForward:
            return "Power Forward"
        case .Center:
            return "Center"
        default:
            "Position doesn't exist"
        }
    }
}

let goldenStateWarriors = BasketballTeam(teamName: "Golden State Warriors")
goldenStateWarriors.numberOfPlayers = 12
goldenStateWarriors.locatedIn = "Oakland, California"
goldenStateWarriors.roster = ["Stephen Curry" : 1, "Andrew Bogut" : 5, "Klay Thompson" : 2]
goldenStateWarriors.roster["Harrison Barnes"] = 3

goldenStateWarriors.printRoster()
goldenStateWarriors.printTeamLocation()

var num = 3

if let numberToPositionConv = NumberedPosition(rawValue: num) {
    let description = numberToPositionConv.labelOfPosition()
}
```